# Get/Set loadOnDemandBufferSize or loadMoreDataRequested through JavaScript

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have a SearchBar on top of RadListView using loadOnDemandBufferSize="10" and when I submit a search the loadMoreDataRequested property is triggered pushing additional items to the search results.

The searchBar uses a different method to retrieve data. I could update the http.getJSON URL used by onLoadMore method but I believe it would be better to temporarily disable the loadOnDemandMode in RadListView.

I just need to temporarily disable the loadMoreDataRequested or set loadOnDemandBufferSize to zero when submitting the search in order to keep the search results alone.

Is there a way to get/set loadMoreDataRequested or loadOnDemandBufferSize using JavaScript? My project is running on Nativescript-Vue.

```
mounted() {
      console.log(this.$refs.listView.nativeView.loadMoreDataRequested)
      console.log(this.$refs.listView.loadMoreDataRequested)
      console.log(this.$refs.listView.nativeView)
      console.log(this.$refs.listView)
}
```

```
<GridLayout columns="*" rows="auto, *, auto">
    <SearchBar @submit="searchHttp" v-model="search" v-show="searchShow" height="50" row="0" />
    <RadListView
      for="item in items"
      loadOnDemandMode="Auto"
      loadOnDemandBufferSize="10"
      @loadMoreDataRequested="onLoadMore"
      @itemTap="onItemTap"
      ref="listView"
      row="1"
    >
      <v-template>
        <StackLayout :class="$odd ? 'list-group-item list-group-item-odd' : 'list-group-item'" orientation="vertical">
          <Label :text="item.created + ' - ' + item.company_id" />
        </StackLayout>
      </v-template>
    </RadListView>
    <Label v-if="items != null && !activity" :text="'Total ' + items.length" class="search-total" height="30" row="2" />
    <ActivityIndicator :busy="activity" borderRadius="50" color="#6c6aa6" width="50" height="50" rowSpan="3" />
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may set the `loadOnDemandMode` property to `None`.

```
import * as RadListViewModule from "nativescript-ui-listview";    

this.$refs.listView.nativeView.loadOnDemandMode = RadListViewModule.ListViewLoadOnDemandMode.None;
```